# Values in Dictionaries during a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

When looping in a dictionary, how do I change the value in the loop.
For example:

```
listt=[1,4,2]
mydict=[a:d, c:b, q:r]
```

I am trying to make:

```
for i in listt:
     for key in mydict:
           mydict[key]=i
```

but this does not work. What occurs is the ith value ends up being the last one. in my new dictionary, so it is always a:2, c:2, etc. Instead of `a:1, b:4, q:2`. I need to store the ith value I think and then use that to change the value in the dictionary. Though I am not sure what I am getting at! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Keys in dicts are not ordered. So you can not control the pairing between items in `listt` and keys in the dict `mydict`.

However, the keys in an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) *are* ordered:

```
import collections

listt=[1,4,2]
mydict=collections.OrderedDict([('a','d'), ('c','b'), ('q','r')])
for item, key in zip(listt, mydict):
    mydict[key] = item

print(mydict)
```

yields

```
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('c', 4), ('q', 2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

there are few misunderstandings with `dict` here:

it seems like you want to 'update' the dictonary with same keys and new values(with values supplied from new list). problem is, a dictonary does not keep stored items in order; a dictionary `{a:d, c:b, q:r}` does not mean you can iterate through the dictionary in `[a, c, q]` order.

also, you're using nested for-loops, that is why every value ends up as last vlues of `listt`.

you can use the collections.OrderedDict to keep things in order. and, instead of nested for-loops, use `zip` to combine iterators.

so, your code would be :

```
from collections import OrderedDict

listt = [1, 4, 2]
mydict = OrderedDict([(a, d), (c, b), (q, r)])

mydict = OrderedDict(zip(mydict.keys(), listt))
```